# Finding count of substring in a column in pandas dataframe and getting the wrong answer

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, substring

So I need to find the count of "tropical" and "fruity" in description column of wines table in kaggle mini course on pandas.

Here is what ive written :

```
count_t = reviews.description.str.count("tropical").sum()
count_f = reviews.description.str.count("fruity").sum()
descriptor_counts = pd.Series([count_t, count_f], index = ['tropical', 'fruity'])
print(descriptor_counts)
```

The output I am getting for this is :

```
tropical    3703
fruity      9259
dtype: int64
```

The solution given on kaggle is :

```
n_trop = reviews.description.map(lambda desc: "tropical" in desc).sum()
n_fruity = reviews.description.map(lambda desc: "fruity" in desc).sum()
descriptor_counts = pd.Series([n_trop, n_fruity], index=['tropical', 'fruity'])
print(descriptor_counts)
```

and output for this correct snippet by kaggle is :

```
tropical    3607
fruity      9090
dtype: int64
```

Why is my code snippet giving a different count than the suggested solution and why is there a difference in count ?

Comment: 'fruity' in 'fruity drink' (`desc`) is `True` (1) while 'fruity' == 'fruity drink' is `False` (0). `str.count` looks for exact equality (==) while `map` + `in` will match substrings in each cell.

Comment: The kaggle solution is not the best. `str.contains` would be more efficient. A regex to match all the terms in one shot would be even better.